# mistake with django STATICFILES_STORAGE

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, static-files, django-cache

I'm working with django, and the settings file I put  the configuration for STATICFILES_STORAGE,

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage'.
```

I run collectstatic and run my app and  the staticfiles has a new file's name but in this new File location 
there are not, the post-processed files  and then my page can't show  fine 
the file would should be in  same ruta the  original static files ?

Comment: What the ruta does ruta mean ?

Comment: this is File location

Comment: Is `DEBUG = True` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: No, I have DEBUG = False

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your problem - pretty much everything from "I run collectstatic". Could you perhaps rephrase it slightly please? Perhaps http://staticfiles.productiondjango.com/blog/setting-up-static-file-caching/ may be of use (disclaimer: I wrote that)